# Boot to shell with Ubuntu MATE 15.04 on Raspberry PI 2

Tags: shell, boot, raspberry-pi2, ubuntu-15.04

Is it possible to boot to the terminal? I've tried to look for a *grub* file but I could not find it. Also */boot/firmware/config.txt* does not seem to have such option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to *Rohith Madhavan* and *AceFace* on [Ubuntu-mate bitbucket issues](https://bitbucket.org/ubuntu-mate/ubuntu-mate-rpi2/issues/4/boot-to-shell-with-ubuntu-mate-1504-on):

You can boot to shell using the following commands:

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target --force
systemctl disable lightdm.service --force
systemctl disable graphical.target --force
systemctl disable plymouth.service --force
```

Replace **disable** with **enable** to boot with GUI again.

Comment: When I boot to the GUI will my wifi still connect automatically. I setup 2 wifi interface in the UI one for acquiring internet through hotspot and the other one is connecting to my local (no internet) network.

Comment: I gues it won't connect to my network automatically, I just tried it.

Comment: Once disabled, I cannot enable again. It will boot only in text mode. Raspberry Pi3.

Answer (score 4):

The proposed solution doesn't work on Ubuntu MATE 16.04 and the "Welcome" application mentions a non-existent "graphical" command. The following worked for me :

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$1" == 'enable' || "$1" == 'disable' ]]; then
    if [ "$1" == 'disable' ]; then
        systemctl set-default multi-user.target --force
    fi

    systemctl $1 lightdm.service --force
    systemctl $1 graphical.target --force
    systemctl $1 plymouth.service --force

    if [ "$1" == 'enable' ]; then
        if [ ! -h /etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service ]; then
            ln -s /lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service /etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service
        fi

        systemctl set-default graphical.target --force
    fi
else
    echo 'Enables or disables GUI at boot.'
    echo "Usage : $(basename) {enable | disable}"
fi
```

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu Mate 18.04.1 LTS, installed inside a virtual machine in VirtualBox. Thanks a lot, mate!

P.S.: If you obtained this from somewhere, cite the source to help others.